# FreeBSD upgrade to RELEASE-pX?

Tags: upgrade, freebsd

I have a FreeBSD-system with stating FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE-p2 and another one stating FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE-p6.

What does the -p2 and -p6 parts of the version name stand for? Am I guessing right that they stand for patch level?

I there a way to directly upgrade from FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE-p2 to FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE-p6 via

```
% freebsd-update upgrade -r 11.1-RELEASE-p6
```

Or how else would I do such a minor upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the patch level. You can roughly read it as `11.1.2` and `11.1.6`, respectively. These versions differ in security updates, usually.

To install the latest security patches you can use `freebsd-update fetch install`.

Comment: It's the patch level of the kernel, actually. If you want the server to report a newer patch level, you need to also reboot the machine after running `freebsd-update fetch install`.

Comment: The note about rebooting is printed by `freebsd-update`, AFAIR, so I omitted that in my answer.

Comment: FreeBSD has a userland utility to check the version without rebooting. Not all patches contain new kernels. For some things, restarting services is enough. You would not use uname -a as that would give you the running kernel, but rather freebsd-version

Answer (score 3):

Correct Your -p2 and -p6 stands for the different security patch levels of your systems. The patch level will be "increased" by running:

```
freebsd-update fetch install   # apply security patches
```

Talking about minor or major upgrades of FreeBSD: Those are the "product versions", this is where the -RELEASE comes into play. It's always something like [major version].[minor version]-RELEASE.

```
# minor upgrade if currently running 11.1-RELEASE, major release is still "11"
freebsd-update -r 11.2-RELEASE upgrade

# major upgrade if currently running e.g. 11.x-RELEASE 
freebsd-update -r 12.0-RELEASE upgrade
```

Fore more details see the [FreeBSD Handbook/Updates](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/updating-upgrading-freebsdupdate.html).

Your current version and patch level of FreeBSD can be determined by running

```
freebsd-version -kru
# installed kernel, running kernel, userland
# those may differ from each other
# see 'man freebsd-version' for more
```